# Проблемы с работой API DirectAdmin

Tags: php, ssl

Есть код, по форумам работает у всех нормально... А у меня нет :)

```
include 'httpsocket.php';
$sock = new HTTPSocket;
$sock->connect('yoursite.com',2222);
$sock->set_login("admin|{username}","{admin_password}");
$sock->set_method('POST');
$sock->query('/CMD_API_SUBDOMAINS',
array(
    'action' => 'create',
    'domain' => '{parent_domain}',
    'subdomain' => '{subdomain_name}'
));
$result = $sock->fetch_body();
echo $result;
```

Этот код добавляет поддомен через панель DA. Но при его выполнении пишет:

```
"DirectAdmin appears to be using SSL. Change your script to connect to ssl://"
```

Я понял что он просит перед адресом сайта написать 'ssl://'. Но, когда вставляю 'ssl://', или ещё пробовал 'https://', никаких ответов не выскакивает, белый лист и не создаётся поддомен. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найден ответ, может кому пригодиться! К домену добавляем **ssl://**, не совсем верно **yoursite.com**, тут должен быть путь к админ панели хостера, в моём случае это было **srv8.kerio-by.org**. Дальше, **admin |** не нужно, **username** и **admin_password** - логин и пасс от панели управления. Последняя строка так же не нужна, в итоге получили:

```
$sock->connect('ssl://srv8.kerio-by.org',2222);
$sock->set_login("login","pass");
```